# Как по имени класса в run-time создать объект?

Tags: java

Доброго всем времени. Читаю книжку (осн.методы класса Object) и пришла в голов идея - по переданному объекту в функции рекурсивно взойти до класса Object и на нисходящем проходе отпечатать иерархию задаваемого изначально объекта. Пример:

```
public static void printParentName( Object obj )
{
    if ( obj.getClass() == Object.class )
        return;

    printParentName( X );
    System.out.println( obj.getClass().getSimpleName() );
}
```

Вопрос: что нужно передать в X, чтобы рекурсия заработала?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static void printParentName(Class<?> clazz) {
    if (clazz == Object.class) {
        return;
    }
    printParentName(clazz.getSuperclass());
    System.out.println(clazz.getSimpleName());
}
```